# Allowed memory size of 335544320 bytes exhausted

Tags: php, wordpress, out-of-memory, memory-limit

I have made my WordPress website recently with godaddy hosting,I have completed all of the parts like design and development you know the site is ok now.But,when I am trying to searching my site on google with this url http://tshirtkings247.com/ then it't getting this error...

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 335544320 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 16896349 bytes) in
>   /home/content/p3pnexwpnas07_data02/85/2640485/html/wp-content/object-cache.php
>   on line 574

How can I fix this problem.please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Godaddy Change php memory limit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915223/godaddy-change-php-memory-limit)

Comment: What do you mean about possible duplicate of Goodaddy? please explain.I need your help.

Comment: Your problem is similar to the linked "godaddy" question someone else asked. Basically your host is only allowing a certain amount of memory to be used by your site, and you're using more than they allow. **Temporary solution:** Contact your host to increase your memory allocation or upgrade your hosting plan. Wordpress sites can use a lot of memory. **Long term solution:** 335 megabytes is a `LOT` of memory, so you should have a web developer look into why it's using so much memory to run a search. Either make it run with less memory or find a new host that can accomodate your huge site.

Comment: Is it possible if I increase my memory limit then the site will be ok?

Comment: @WasimRana increasing the memory will temporarily fix the problem and stop the errors, but it shouldn't take that much memory to search. You need to discover what is causing Wordpress to use so much memory when searching.

Comment: when I search my site then it's showing this....Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 335544320 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 16896349 bytes) in /home/content/p3pnexwpnas07_data02/85/2640485/html/wp-content/object-cache.php on line 574   what is the real meaning of this error?please explain..thanks

Comment: No need to repeat your question in the comments. It's all explained above and at the question I linked. Search "wordpress php memory limit" for all you'd want to know.